# Sending Email with Large Attachment (20-50MB) via SMTP in PowerShell - "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" Error

Tags: powershell, email

I'm attempting to send an email using PowerShell, and I need to attach a zip file that's around 20-50MB in size. I'm encountering an issue with the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet where I'm getting the following error:

```
Send-MailMessage : Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

```
$from = "murat@abc.com"
$to = "azamat@abc.com"
$subject = "Report is attached. Please take a look!"
$body = "This is a report email "

$attachment = "report.txt"
$encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8

Send-MailMessage -From $from -To $to -Subject $subject -Body $body -Encoding $encoding -Attachments $attachment -SmtpServer "smtp.abc.com"
```

I suspect that the issue might be related to the large attachment size, but I'm not sure how to handle it. Is there a way to properly send a large attachment via an SMTP server using PowerShell?

Comment: for exchange have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/message-size-limits?view=exchserver-2019

Comment: You really should not try to send 20+ MB files as email attachment anyway. Many popular mail services do not allow large attachments. Use a file sharing service instead.

Comment: What code exactly do you use for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause is due to the size of the attachment, hence the "forcibly closed by the by remote host" error you're seeing. The server has started receiving the message, determined the size to be too large, and closed the connection.

Have you checked whether you get the same issue if the attachment is smaller?

As vonPryz has mentioned, email isn't really the ideal method for sending large attachments, and 20MB is quite a common size limit with many email providers, so it's worth checking what your provider has it configured as. If you're sending via your own mail server then you may be able to increase that limit, but keep in mind if those emails are being sent onto someone external then THEY might not be able to receive them.

For example, a quick look online shows that Gmail's current limit is 25MB and Outlook.com's is 34MB.

Also keep in mind that the size limit is based on the encoded size, NOT the size of the file(s) on your computer. Typically you can expect to see the size of the attachment increase by as much as a third once it has been encoded for email transmission. So if you have a 24MB file, the encoded email going through the server could well be 32MB. There's a good explanation of why here https://superuser.com/questions/1139323/why-is-the-size-of-my-email-about-a-third-bigger-than-the-size-of-its-attached-f